# Error with new class

Tags: android

For the class declaration i get this error: "The method onCreate(Bundle) of type XylophoneActivity must override or implement a supertype method" and not sure why.

```
public class XylophoneActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xylophone_layout);

  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `@Override` tag.

Comment: make sure you have the updated adt and eclipse

Comment: Removing the override worked, thanks

Comment: @user2253722 Don't remove the `override` annotation, please change your java version `1.5` to `1.6` or higher, this will solve your problem